# what 's the differene between "bower install -save package" and "bower install package "?

Tags: javascript, bower

I know "-save"  will add a record to dependencies block in bower.json ,but I DON'T know the function of dependencies , it's just a hint text for user?

Comment: once it is added to bower.json. in future when you copy your code to a different system you can simply do bower install and all the packages will be downloaded based on the entries in bower.json.

Comment: `--save` saves the package in `bower.json`

Comment: @RayonDabre: yes for `npm`, no for `bower` (it uses `bower.json`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--save` argument tells bower to update `bower.json`, which lists the packages that you have installed. That way, you include `bower.json` and your own code in source control, but not all the bower components. When checking the project out of source control, you run `bower install` to install everything from `bower.json` in the checked-out base.

From [the documentation](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install):

**install options**

- `-F`, `--force-latest`: Force latest version on conflict
- `-p`, `--production`: Do not install project devDependencies
- `-S`, `--save`: Save installed packages into the project’s `bower.json` dependencies
- `-D`, `--save-dev`: Save installed packages into the project’s `bower.json` `devDependencies`
- `-E`, `--save-exact`: Configure installed packages with an exact version rather than semver